# Use a specific version of Node.js globally

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Can I establish Node.js tool installer task globally, For the whole project instead of running it before every pipeline ?

Comment: You need to give a bit more context. Is this part of a pipeline, or is it on your local machine? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The general task : Applying Azure CI/CD over an Angular Project ,
I wonder if I can set The default version of node for the project/azure server , rather than running the mentioned task (Node.js tool installer) before each pipeline

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot establish a task globally. Azure devops doesnot have this feature yet.

If you are running your pipeline on your self-hosted agent. You can install the specific version Node.js to the self-hosted agent machine, and you donot need to use Node.js tool installer in your pipeline. The node.js installed on the local machine will be used.

If you donot want to manually add Node.js tool installer task in your pipeline. You can convert an existing pipeline to a template(Select your pipeline and click the 3dots on the top right corner shown as below screenshot). Then next time you create a new pipeline, you can just select the custom pipeline template, and the same tasks will be added to this new pipeline.

[image]